# How to scroll to a specific event after removing class

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, scrollto

I have a scenario where a clipped image fully expands with a click event and then returns back to the clipped image with another click event. These images are long, so I need the browser to scroll back to the top of the clipped image on the second click event, which returns the image to the smaller, clipped size.

To trigger the image resizing, I am simply using a jQuery click function, shown here:

```
 jQuery("#zoom").on('click', function(){

   $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

 });
```

I can implement a scroll function with jQuery. I don't know how to trigger a scroll only when the active class is removed in accordance with the code above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a global boolean and use an if-statement, like so:

```
 var active = true;

 jQuery("#zoom").on('click', function(){

   $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

   if(!active){
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: $("body").offset().top}, 1000); //1000 is the speed of the animation
    active = true;
   }
   else active = false;

 });
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you so much.  Works flawlessly, and I learned something.  Thanks for your time.